# Caliburn Micro Bindable collection - binding to combobox item source displays wrong text

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, caliburn.micro

I have this stupid problem. I bind from view model class property type of BindableCollection to the ItemSource property of ComboBox control.

Code from view model class:

```
public class SpiritUser
{
    public string Nick { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}


    public BindableCollection<SpiritUser> SpiritUsers
    {
        get { return _spiritUsers; }
        set
        {
            _spiritUsers = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SpiritUsers);
        }
    }


//constructor of view model class
        public LogOnViewModel()
        {
            SpiritUsers = new BindableCollection<SpiritUser>
                        {
                            new SpiritUser
                                {
                                    Nick = "Spirit_1",
                                    Password = "slniecko1"
                                },
                            new SpiritUser
                                {
                                    Nick = "Spirit_2",
                                    Password = "slniecko1"
                                }
                        };
        }
```

In view I have this:

```
  Style on comboBox:

    <Style x:Key="LogOnView_NickComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Nick}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,4,10,4"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
```

ComboBox control:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SpiritUsers, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Style="{StaticResource LogOnView_NickComboBox}"
          SelectedValuePath="Nick"
          Text="{Binding Path=Nick, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Nick, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="True"/>
```

If I select some comboBox item I see  **Spirit.Models.SpiritUser**  instead of item text.

Problem cause if comboBox property IsEditable is set on true.

How can I solve this problem, I need bind property from view model on comboBox but also I need have comboBox editable and bind user input to property in view model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of editable combobox use DisplayMemberPath property instead of ItemTemplate to specify what property of bound object you want to be displayed:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SpiritUsers, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Style="{StaticResource LogOnView_NickComboBox}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Nick"
          SelectedValuePath="Nick"
          Text="{Binding Path=CurrentUserNick, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="True"/>
```

In case if you still want to use ItemTemplate then you can specify what property of you object should be displayed in the text box via TextSearch.TextPath attached property:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SpiritUsers, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Style="{StaticResource LogOnView_NickComboBox}"
          SelectedValuePath="Nick"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Nick"
          Text="{Binding Path=CurrentUserNick, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="True"/>
```

Comment: Thank Mr. Glazkov, first solution is very elegant :)